# Error en promesa. Me dice que no es una función

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando cargar contenido de un archivo JSON para después pasarlo al HTML mediante un forEach y la propiedad innerHTML. En principio, cargo el contenido del JSON mediante una promesa utilizando async/await.
Me marca el error siguiente:

```
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: productos.forEach is not a function
at Desplegar.desplegarProductos (scripts.js:44:19)
at scripts.js:21:15"
```

No logro entender porqué la función no sirve. O acaso cometí un error a la hora de establecer la promesa ?

Esto es mi código :

```
// Variables principales
const productosDOM = document.querySelector (".productos-card-container")

// Función para activar contenido del DOM mediante un evento
document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const productos = new Productos ()
    const desplegar = new Desplegar ()
    // Activar array "Panes" desde el JSON
    productos.getProductos ().then (resultado => 
    desplegar.desplegarProductos (resultado))
})


// Crear clase "Productos" para cargar productos desde el JSON 
class Productos {
    // Definir getter con operador get. Utilizo async/await para cumplir la promesa.
    async getProductos () {
        try {
        let contenido = await fetch ("../farina-rustica-productos.json")
        let resultado = await contenido.json ()
        return resultado
        } catch (error) {
            console.log (error);
        }
    }
}

// Crear clase "Desplegar" para mostrar los productos cargados por la clase "Productos" o el Local Storage en la página web
class Desplegar {
    desplegarProductos (productos) {
        let productosHtml = ""
        // Utilizo el método forEach para que todas las propiedas de cada producto aparezcan en el HTML
        productos.forEach (producto => {
            productosHtml +=
//Aqui va mi codigo HTML//
        })
        // Utilizo la propiedad innerHTML para mostrar cada producto con sus propiedades en el HTML
        productosDOM.innerHTML = productosHtml
    }
}
```

Comment: las funciones de flecha no se usan en un bloque productos.forEach (producto => {, prueba esto productos.forEach (function(producto){
[referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Estas iterando sobre un string y no sobre un `objeto` o `array`.

Comment: Roberto, nos muestras el contenido del json, segundo, puedes loguear el valor de `resultado`, y tercero aunque no es la causa de tu error, fíjate que en caso de error, getProductos no retorna, luego `resultado` es undefined?

Comment: @John Las funciones flecha se pueden usar (y suele ser donde más se usan) en las funciones para recorrer arrays como forEach o map

Comment: Dos detalles sobre el código: en el método `getProductos` puedes devolver directamente `return contenido.json()`, ya que esa función va a devolver siempre una promesa. Por otro lado, parece que el error es causado porque el JSON de la respuesta no es una colección/array de elementos y por tanto no tiene el método `forEach`. Comprueba si `productos instanceof Array` es true